# Создание отчетов в reportviewer из хранимой процедуры

Tags: c#, sql-server, reportviewer

Использую SQL Server 2014, VS 2017
Суть в том, что нужно по параметрам создавать отчеты, например, вывести какие-нибудь записи за указанный период времени.
Я пытался сделать это следующим образом:

1. Написать хранимую процедуру для вывода отчета
2. Через DataSet вывести в reportViewer (т к отчеты используют DataSet)

В итоге процедуру написал, результат вывел в DataSet и на этом все:

```
string sqlExpression = "Вывод_всего_транспорта";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SQL.connString))
{
      connection.Open();
      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlExpression, connection);
      command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
      da.Fill(ds);
}
```

Дальше, как ни пытался в reportViewer не выводится ничего? Буду рад любой помощи

Answer (score 1):

Мой ответ не претендует на решение Вашего вопроса, но я покажу как реализован вывод отчетов у меня. Может пригодится или натолкнет на мысль.

Предположим у нас есть форма (Form1), на которой находятся DataGridView для вывода данных из БД, два datetimepicker для фильтрации по времени и кнопка "Отчет". По нажатию кнопки открывается вторая форма (Form2), на которой лежит компонент reportviewer.

В Form1 создаем следующий метод и кидаем в обработчик кнопки "Отчет":

```
void Nakladnaya()
        {
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            {
                var aktIds = new List<int>();

                // получаем список id записей в таблице
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    aktIds.Add((int)row.Cells["pit_id"].Value);
                }

                //открываем форму с отчетом
                var reportForm = new PriemIzTZAReport("Прием из ТЗА", aktIds);
                reportForm.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Нет данных для экспорта");
            }
```

Метод для фильтрации данных в DataGridView с помощью двух datetimepicker:

```
 if (dateTimePicker1.Checked)
        {
            filterStr += " and pit_date_ins >= '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "'";
        }

        if (dateTimePicker2.Checked)
        {
            string dt_do = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString();
            filterStr += " and pit_date_ins <= '" + dt_do + "'";
        }

        if (dataGridView1.DataSource != null)
        {
            (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = filterStr;
        }
```

Во второй форме код выглядит следующим образом:

```
    private readonly string headerText;
    private List<int> aktIds;

    public PriemIzTZAReport()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public PriemIzTZAReport(string headerText, List<int> aktIds)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.headerText = headerText;
        this.aktIds = aktIds;
    }

    private void PriemIzTZAReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Text = headerText;

            var dt = BaseWorker.GetPriemIzTZAReport(aktIds);
            if (dt == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Не удалось получить данные из БД");
            }

            var rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

В моем случае, в классе BaseWorker лежат запросы и процедуры для обращения к БД

```
 var dt = BaseWorker.GetPriemIzTZAReport(aktIds);
```

Код в классе Baseworker:

```
//формирование отчета прием из тза
        internal static DataTable GetPriemIzTZAReport(List<int> aktIds)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = BaseWorker.GetConnection();
            try
            {
                var stringIds = new StringBuilder();

                aktIds.ForEach(id => stringIds.Append($"{id},"));

                var sqlQueryString = $"SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WHERE pit_id IN({stringIds.ToString().TrimEnd(',')})";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQueryString, conn);
                DataTable data = null;
                SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = null;
                //формируем и устанавливаем источник данных для таблицы
                data = new DataTable();
                dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                dataAdapter.Fill(data);
                if (data.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                return data;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Далее на вторую форму добавляем компонент reportviewer, создаем новый отчет, указываем DataSet1, выбираем или создаем источник данных, выбираем нужную таблицу, рисуем шаблон, и указываем какие столбцы хотим выводить.